# How class member variables(instance variable) can be initialized if the memory is given only during object initialisation?

Tags: java, class, oop

As we know that a class can have objects which get memory only by new classname().
Then how it is possible to assign some value to an instance of a class.

```
class Work{
   public int a = 55;
}

class DoStuff{
      public static void main(String[] args){
      Work obj = new Work(); // intialises variable now
      System.out.println(obj.a) // a already has value 55
   }
}
```

Comment: use getter and setter

Answer (score 1):

Order of execution of Initialization blocks and constructor in Java

- Static initialization blocks will run whenever the class is loaded first time in JVM
- Initialization blocks run in the same order in which they appear in the program.
- Instance Initialization blocks are executed whenever the class is initialized and before constructors are invoked. They are typically placed above the constructors within braces.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/order-execution-initialization-blocks-constructors-java/

So in your case `public int a = 55;` is invoked before constructor of `Work` class.
JVM first reserves memory for an object and then starts initialization of all object properties.